# How to acess @IBOutlet weak var

Tags: ios, swift

Just starting out with swift. Have few UI on screen, want to do something with the UI when a certain condition is followed.
The question is when we drag the UI and get access to things like @IBoutlet like the one below

```
 @IBOutlet weak var modifiedSegmentLoginRegister: UISegmentedControl!
```

How to access it outside

```
func  viewDidLoad(){
its accessible here 
}
```

But not acessible outside

cannot get modifiedSegmentLoginRegister here.

Comment: show us the whole class

Comment: @JAL I just re-checked. You can't drag the outlet into the `func` scope. It's only possible to drag into the `class` scope. Why: because the class represents an instance of the VC that is on the storyboard and the property you are creating (by dragging) is the property of the instance of the class and it can't be dragged into the function. Please let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: @TungFam You're probably right, this was just a guess while I was away from Xcode.  Either way, I think the issue is that the outlet was set up incorrectly.

Comment: @JAL the outlet was dragged at the class scope wanted to get the outlet(UIContainer)( which has three text fields) to display things on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access it because it's how it is designed (for now this info will be enough).

What you need to do to access it: Create functions that will trigger your event when you need to do those checks for those certain conditions. In those functions you can access the Outlet.

For example: add the button to your `ViewController` > drag it into the code > choose `Action` (but not `Outlet`) > in that method try to do what you need (check those conditions etc) > you will see that the `Outlet` will be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

So, IBOutlets aren't actually loaded until the view is loaded. So they wouldn't actually be usable until viewDidLoad is called. You could create a var in your VC and then interact with it there, then add it to the view

```
view.addSubview(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are trying access a property or method of the UISegmentedControl.
Such as:
`modifiedSegmentLoginRegister.setTitle("A" :forSegmentAt: 0)`

The IBOutlet is just like any other variable. It can be declared or initialized as an instance variable outside of a function. However, if you want to change it or access it, you need to do that inside a function, such as viewDidLoad. You cannot access "access it outside".

Comment: Thanks for the info, so is there any possible way to do it outside the scope of viewDidLoad?

Comment: You can access it inside any function. For example you could hook up a button, or some other kind of IBAction. Or you could create your own function that viewDidLoad or something else calls.